# Constructing a regex with three subpatterns and a maximum length of 28 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create an expression that fit this requirements :

- The string must be composed by 3 substring
- The first substring accept 0-9a-zA-Z, the minimum length is 1 and there is notte max length
- The second substring must be " - "
- The last have The first's one same condition
- Total maximum string length must be 28 chars

It is possible to accomplish this requirement with Regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following regex should work fine:

```
/(?=^.{3,28}$)[^\W_]+\-[^\W_]+/
```

```js
var array = [
  "123456790-123456789012345678",
  "123456790-1234567890123456789",
  "adsd-dsds"
];
var re = /(?=^.{3,28}$)[^\W_]+\-[^\W_]+/;
array.forEach(e => console.log(re.test(e) ? e.match(re)[0]: "match failed"));
```

**Breakdown** shamelessly copied from regex101.com:

- Positive Lookahead `(?=^.{3,28}$)`

  - `^` asserts position at start of a line
  - `.{3,28}` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `{3,28}` Quantifier — Matches between 3 and 28 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\W_]+`

  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\W` matches any non-word character (equal to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `_` matches the character `_` literally (case sensitive)
  - `\-` matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^\W_]+`

  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\W` matches any non-word character (equal to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `_` matches the character `_` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks Aniket !!!!!!! It works fine !!!!!!

Comment: @Monica Do not use `[A-z]` to match all ASCII letters, use `[A-Za-z]`. See [Why is this regex allowing a caret?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)